# Error: cannot find symbol class Base64

Tags: java, android

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import java.util.Base64;
```

It gives me an error when I run the code.

```
    private void upload() {
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bao);
    byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

    // Upload image to server
    new uploadToServer().execute();

}
```

**The errors I got are:**

```
Error:(81, 21) error: cannot find symbol method encodeBytes(byte[])
Error:(43, 25) error: cannot find symbol class Base64
```

Comment: Import them  just . `import android.util.Base64;`

Comment: I have used two import statements. The errors are same.

Comment: If you have **two** import statements importing the same class, then how should the compiler know, *which one* to use?

Comment: This may sound cheap but did you save the file after adding imports?

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild` please

Comment: Remove `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya The error got resolved after removing import org.apache line.

And, now there's another error in same method, [ error: cannot find symbol method encodeBytes(byte[]) ]

Answer (score 4):

You are importing Java library. Use android library for Base64 instead.

```
import android.util.Base64;
```

Comment: Good call! I didn't notice that!

Comment: Same happens when importing DateTime Utils. Both java as well as android library have classes for them. A novice user easily gets confused between them.

Comment: Yep that's right, not any Java libray is available under Android. Take Swing and AWT for example.

Comment: import android.util.Base64; is available only  since Java 8

Comment: @Vasanth buddy I nowhere mentioned any Java library class. I'm talking about Android's android.util.Base64; which I think has no link with Java 8 or Java 7.
Also, since everyday some of the functions/methods and other features of Android/Java are getting deprecated alongwith the advancement of technology and feature advancements, there is no point using older version on Java/Android SDK.